# React JSX not being recognized?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using these 2 CDN's to include React libraries in my project, however when I go to render some html using JSX onto the body of a HTML document it doesent recognize the JSX as JSX (I'm using chrome), and consequently throws up an error as it's reading the JSX as javascript.
Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be great :)
CDN's:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="here"></div>  
</body>
```

React:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const text = <h1>Hello World</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(text, document.getElementById('here'));
```

Comment: The react library does not recognize jsx. You will need a library like babel to parse your jsx.

Comment: React Code need to be transpiled by babel so include babel and add script to babel type - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/web-slate/react-multiple-events-without-bind/master/standalone/1.bind-events.html

Answer (score 1):

You need a `babel` to use `JSX`.

Two ways to add `babel` to your project are,

1. **Add `CDN` for `babel`**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can use `JSX` in any `<script>` tag by adding `type="text/babel"` attribute to it.

For example,

```
<script type="text/babel">
   const text = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
   ReactDOM.render(
      text,
      document.getElementById('root')
   );
</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/pajipaxeha/1/edit?html,output)

2. **Install `babel` using `npm`**,

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)

> Adding JSX to a project doesn’t require complicated tools like a bundler or a development server. Essentially, adding JSX is a lot like adding a CSS preprocessor. The only requirement is to have Node.js installed on your computer.

Go to your project folder in the terminal, and paste these two commands:

```
Step 1: Run npm init -y (If you get an "Invalid name" error when you run npm init -y, rename the project folder to only contain lowercase ASCII letters or hyphens (e.g. my-project), and try again.)

Step 2: Run npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3
```

Comment: It's saying require isn't defined in the babel CDN's when I add them, Idk why this is so hard for me lmao

Comment: Have you seen the Demo provided? When using babel CDN, you need to write your script in `html` file only with `<script>` tag and `type="text/babel"` as attribute